# killing loop inside each

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to kill the loop inside each?
i mean here is my code when QUERY is has 100 results and somehow(i will be so happy if you would explain me why) the alert pops 100 times after clicking ONLY one one result
(clicking on one result needs to pop the alert 1 time)

```
var tit_id = '#tit_' + this.SN;
function paintDATA(QUERY) {
    var incld = '<div>';

    $.each(QUERY, function () {
        if (this.wCount != 0) {
            $(tit_id).click(function () {      
                alert('RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR')
            });



<div id="tit_' + shipment + '">
```

Comment: You said that QUERY had 100 results. So your `$.each` is executing 100 times, and each time, it's attaching *another* event handler to `tit_id`. When you click, all 100 event handlers run.

Comment: From the jQuery docs of .each():
"We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."

Comment: Could you please provide a complete code example? The code you provided is not valid JavaScript. Also, where are you modifying `this.wCount`?

Comment: What do you mean with "kill the loop"? A break statement?

What should happen when you click on that element?

Please restructure your code for better readability.

Comment: @FelixKling: the function will be called *on* each element, so `this` refers to another context every time.

Comment: @Bergi: I know, that was not my question. Comparing `this.wCount` seems to be useless if it is not modified. I'm just wondering what this comparison is for.

Comment: but i dont want to break the each i just want the alert will pop only one time and Each will run to the next...if there would be 1000 results i need that the alert will pop one time and only for results that been clicked

Comment: the compartion is just checking if the wCount is not empty.. the code above is just an example to ask you how to break inside EACH its not a real code...using this code i showing my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each element returned by the query, you're attaching the same handler on the same element:

Did you want to attach the click handler on each item returned instead?

```
$.each(QUERY, function () {
    if (this.wCount != 0) {
        $(this).click(function () {      
            alert('RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR')
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

So if you want to alert, then exit from the each loop, you can, like Jasper says, return false from the each callback:

```
$.each(QUERY, function () {
    if (this.wCount != 0) {
        $(this).click(function () {      
            alert('RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR')
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to break the each i just want the alert will pop only one time and Each will run to the next...if there would be 1000 results i need that the alert will pop one time and only for results that been clicked

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you're asking. If you want to break a `$.each()` loop you can `return false;`.

The documentation states:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Documentation link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ (look just before the examples)

Comment: but i dont want to break the each i just want the alert will pop only one time and Each will run to the next...if there would be 1000 results i need that the alert will pop one time and only for results that been clicked